# C: Finished Tic Tac Toe program, looking for tips to improve it

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

I have finished up my code since  last time(thanks to everyone's help!).

Comment: The code you specifically need help with is trying to assign a value to a function call which doesn't return anything (at least according to its signature).

Comment: board[0][0] = 'O'; display_board(); Note that the display_board() function does not "return the pointer char** board"; instead it "takes char **board as a parameter".

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll have to read up that more.

Comment: You can try on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 % sure that your code is supposed to be a complete game, but I can change the return values so that your code compiles and starts the Tic-Tac-Toe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **display_board(char **board) {   //Create board function

    const char NUM_COLS = 3;
    const char NUM_ROWS = 3;
    const char BLANK_SPACE = '*';

    int i, j, k, l;
    board = (char **) malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        board[i] = (char *) malloc(NUM_COLS * sizeof(char));

        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            board[i][j] = BLANK_SPACE;
        }

        //Display board function
    }

    for (k = 0; k < NUM_ROWS; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < NUM_ROWS; l++) {
            printf("%c", board[k][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return board;
}

int main() {
    char **board;
    int row, col;
    const char BLANK_SPACE = '*';

    int turn, i;
    turn = 0;

    display_board(board);

    //need while !game_not_over conditional statement

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        turn + 1;
    }

    if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        printf("O's turn\n");
        printf("Make your move");
        scanf("%d, %d", &row, &col);

        if ((row == 0 && col == 0) && (board[0][0] == BLANK_SPACE)) {
            display_board(board);
            board[0][0] = '0';
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Test

```
Debug/gnu
***
***
***
O's turn
Make your move***
```

Comment: `display_board(board);` --> `board = display_board(board);` Also Cause a memory leak. So split to `create_board` and `display_board`.

Comment: The program is definitely not 100% complete, but this specific problem had me stuck for awhile.

Ohh the memory leak problem makes so much sense! No wonder my program kept crashing but didn't show any problems. Next thing I'll work on splitting creating and displaying the board. Thanks a lot for the helpful tips!